# How do I program a loop in R?

Tags: r, loops

I would like to programm a loop in R to write data frames.

I tried this:

```r
dts <- c('r1', 'r2', 'r3', 'r4', 'r5')
for (dt in dts){
  temp <- data.frame(S=paste0(dt,"_RAW$Zeit"), A=paste0(dt,"_RAW$Wert"))
  assign(dt, temp)
}
```

But it did not work. The data frame is not correct (there are no values, only these two lines):

```r
  | S           | A
-----------------------------
1 | r1_RAW$Zeit | r1_RAW$Wert
```

I expect this:

```r
r1 <- data.frame(S=r1_RAW$Zeit, A=r1_RAW$Wert)
r2 <- data.frame(S=r2_RAW$Zeit, A=r2_RAW$Wert)
...
```

Comment: Which values are you talking about?

Comment: There are however much better solutions, but try replacing `paste0(dt,"_RAW$Zeit")` with `get(paste0(dt,"_RAW"))$Zeit`.  Notice there is a difference between an object name `r1_RAW$Zeit` and the character vector representing it `"r1_RAW$Zeit"`.

Comment: Thank you for your time, but unfortunately it doesn't work. I get `Error: $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors`. What would be a better solution? Please give me a hint...

Comment: Notice that your question is not [reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/3277821).  For example, what are the `r*_RAW` objects?

Comment: These are dataframes, imported from csv files.

Comment: They have ten columns, but I only need these two (S=Zeit, A=Wert).

Comment: Since there is no reproducible example, the method here might help you [R use paste function as a object in subset function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49655013/r-use-paste-function-as-a-object-in-subset-function)

Comment: Thank you @deepseefan! Now it is working, but it leaves out the underscores... What can I do here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trick is to use `mget` to get all input dataframes at once, outside the `for` loop. Then, in the loop, extract the columns of interest and `assign` the new data sets.

```
dts <- c("r1", "r2", "r3")
r_RAW_list <- mget(paste0(dts, "_RAW"))

for(d in dts){
  i <- grep(d, names(r_RAW_list))
  temp_rRAW <- r_RAW_list[[i]]
  temp <- data.frame(S = temp_rRAW[["Zeit"]], A = temp_rRAW[["Wert"]])
  assign(d, temp)
}
rm(r_RAW_list, temp_rRAW, temp)

ls(pattern = "^r[[:digit:]]$")
#[1] "r1" "r2" "r3"

r1
#            S           A
#1  -1.2070657 -0.47719270
#2   0.2774292 -0.99838644
#3   1.0844412 -0.77625389
#4  -2.3456977  0.06445882
#5   0.4291247  0.95949406
#6   0.5060559 -0.11028549
#7  -0.5747400 -0.51100951
#8  -0.5466319 -0.91119542
#9  -0.5644520 -0.83717168
#10 -0.8900378  2.41583518
```

**Test data creation code.**

```
set.seed(1234)
n <- 10
r1_RAW <- data.frame(Zeit = rnorm(n), Wert = rnorm(n), Other = rnorm(n))
r2_RAW <- data.frame(Zeit = rnorm(n), Wert = rnorm(n), Other = rnorm(n))
r3_RAW <- data.frame(Zeit = rnorm(n), Wert = rnorm(n), Other = rnorm(n))
```